# Android chathead is killed when I open game

Tags: android

I'm using https://github.com/recruit-lifestyle/FloatingView 
to create chathead like messenger on android.
But when I open a game, the chathead get killed.
Is there any way to display the chathead above the game?
Please help, thanks

Config of WindowManager in the lib:

```
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    mMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mMetrics);
    mParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    mParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    mParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE;
    mParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
    mParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

Comment: why i get down vote?

Comment: What is your code?  And yes, your question is being downvoted because it does not fulfill a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i use the lib, please check link above

Comment: i think the question is clear